# Maximum value of a given function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is to find the maximum value of the function:

$f(x)= \frac{|x|-2 -x^2}{|x| +1}$.

What I tried to do was maximise the numerator and minimise the denominator to obtain the maximum value of the function, which was of no use.

I thought maybe I could use the AM-GM inequality but I have no idea how to implement that here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider taking $|x|+1$ out of the numerator, and dropping the || anyway, and treating x as either + or -.

Comment: Definitely: first find the maximum value for $x\ge0$, then find the maximum value for $x\ge0$ (for which $|x|=-x$), then take the greater of the two.